# Spring + Testcontainers + Jpa + Oracle database with multiple user/schema

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jpa, testcontainers

I have an application which I'm trying to test with testcontainers. The database is oracle-xe from testcontainers.
The properties file has the property `jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = true` for automatically discover the schema. The problem here is that I have entities from several schemas/users and seems this does not work well with oracle-xe testcontainer (if I remove de attribute 'schema' from @Table annotations in entities it works fine).

I use as a workaround a schema.sql file to load the schema and it works fine, but I would like to achieve the same without this file.
Does anyone know why this behavior occurs and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Oracle XE Docker image where you create the various schemas and then use this image with TestContainers.

Comment: This does not fit for me because I have to use a specific docker image and it does not have the schemas.

Comment: So you can create a new image that bases on that image. That's the purpose of layering in Docker

Answer (score 0):

If this is still an issue... here's my 2 cents.

Are the *user* and the *schema* different?
If so, you'll probably have to manually create a user for the schema (hint... creating a user creates a schema for the given username).
From Oracle's official docs concerning [CREATE SCHEMA](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6014.htm)

> Note:
>
> This statement does not actually create a schema. Oracle Database
> automatically creates a schema when you create a user (see CREATE
> USER). This statement lets you populate your schema with tables and
> views and grant privileges on those objects without having to issue
> multiple SQL statements in multiple transactions.

Furthermore you will probably need some extra GRANTs etc. to make sure that the user connecting to the DB and the user related to the schema have enough privileges.

Example:

```
CREATE USER <USERNAME> IDENTIFIED BY <password>;
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO <USERNAME>;
GRANT CREATE SESSIONT TO <USERNAME>;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, DBA TO <USERNAME>;
```

FYI... I am, nor claim to be, in **no way** an Oracle Database expert. So check with your DBA to be sure ;)

---

##### Extra information considering oracle DB image for testcontainer

In a similar situation, I've created an oracle-image without the data-volume, using parts of [this](https://medium.com/@ggajos/drop-db-startup-time-from-45-to-3-minutes-in-dockerized-oracle-19-3-0-552068593deb) blog. This allows for an initialized state of the DB.